# Programmatically start a call with IBM Voice Gateway

Tags: twilio, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation, watson-dialog, ibm-voice-gateway

I have connected a IBM Voice Agent (https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/voice-agent/getting-started.html) with a Watson Assistant and a Twilio number.

I am able to call my Twilio number and follow a conversation with the assistant.

Now however, I don't want the user to call the number, but rather I want to programmatically trigger the call. Call some API to force the assistant to call some number. Ideally passing some context with it...

I know that Voice Agent uses Voice Gateway behind the scenes (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4U29/welcome_voicegateway.html).

Update:

I was able to trigger a call by via Twilio. I ask Twilio to act as an intermediate. Twilio will call both my number and the SIP (Voice Agent) and bridge the call. However I am unable to pass any initial parameters to Watson Assistant since I don't control the process...

Comment: not sure if this would be useful https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011213347-Passing-custom-information-via-requests-to-Twilio  the x-* parameters are included in the SIP header

Comment: True, but Voice Agent doesn’t support that...

Comment: Voice Agent now supports the ability to extract a customer parameter from the inbound SIP INVITE. So x-* parameters will work.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, IBM Voice Agent with Watson now allows end users to configure a custom header to extract from inbound SIP INVITE messages. Go to the "Advanced" section under "Edit Voice Agent" to configure it.